# Errors installing libGDX for Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, libgdx

I am currently trying to install libGDX for the Eclipse IDE. Upon setting libGDX up and getting it installed, I received a few errors. At first I thought it was that I didn't have the GWT SDK installed, which was true, so I installed it. It corrected one of the errors but these two persist. I was following the Getting started video at [GetStarted](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/getstarted.html). I received these two errors which seem to be stemmed together:

```
(1)
Description: The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved
Resource: my-gdx-game-html
Path: n/a       
Location: Unknown
Type: Java Problem

(2)
D: Unbound classpath container: 'GWT SDK [missing]' in project 'my-gdx-game-html'   
R: my-gdx-game-html
P: n/a
L: Build path
T: Build Path Problem
```

I have tried doing the Quick Fix option (by right clicking on the error itself in Problems) but when I am taken to a new window, it gives me a couple options under 'Select a fix', either 'Configure build path' or 'Replace with other library.' With my resource 'my-gdx-game-html' ticked, I select 'Finish' which promptly takes me to the Java Build Path. It automatically takes me to the 'Order and Export' tab and I have tried messing around with the 8 options (7 clickable) selecting various ones and hoping for a fix. After selecting 'OK' though, the same result is yielded every time and nothing happens. I am quite unsure what to do at this point and have yet to find other answers online. Any suggestions? Anyone know? Does someone have a link to direct me elsewhere? I have been searching for a few hours now.

Comment: Download the source code and examples from here :-https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx

Comment: Thanks Ali Imran! It did the trick. Should I be concerned about the 390 warnings?

Comment: Yes they are normal i think :)

Comment: While I am at it, would you know why I am not being given the option of being able to run my projects as web apps?

Comment: I have used libGdx only for android so no idea of web :)

Comment: It wasn't necessary! Just making sure I do not make any oversights. Thank you for all your help Ali!

Answer (score 0):

Install Google Web Toolkit (use correct Eclipse Version):

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/usingeclipse